# What is sigma factor PvdS?

Tags: bioinformatics, bacteriology, transcription-factor, archaea, motifs

I am using MEME suite tool for de novo motif discovery and when I use TomTom to compare my motifs with known motif database, I find that my genes could potentially be upregulated or downregulated by *sigma factor PvdS*. I would like to understand what *sigma factor PvdS* exactly means.

I am not really able to interpret the [UniProt](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/G3XCV1) page. It indicates the **protein**: sigma factor PvdS and **gene**: PvdS. Then it is difficult for me to put together the **GO-Molecular Function** and the **GO-Biological Function** in order to understand what *sigma factor PvdS* means.

From the paper by [Miyazaki et al.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7651323/), I find:

> **In response to iron limitation Pseudomonas aeruginosa PAO induces production of pyoverdin, a low-molecular-weight siderophore able to capture ferric ion with a very high affinity. The pvd genes involved in the pyoverdin biosynthesis** are organized in a chromosomal region termed the pvd region, and expression of some pvd genes is regulated at the transcriptional level. Two sets of promoter regions for the pvd genes were defined that were transcriptionally derepressed under iron-limiting conditions. Analysis of transcription from such promoters in Escherichia coli led to **isolation and identification of a positive regulatory gene, pvdS, for expression of the pvd genes, and pvdS was localized in the pvd region.**

From this extract, I can understand that PvdS is a *positive regulatory gene* that is, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulator_gene):

> A regulator gene, regulator, or regulatory gene is a gene involved in controlling the expression of one or more other genes. Regulatory sequences, which encode regulatory genes, are often at the five prime end (5') to the start site of transcription of the gene they regulate.

And so PvdS regulates the expression of the pvd gene involved in the pyoverdin biosynthesis.

Then in the paper by [Tracey et al](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12368452/) I find that:

> **PvdS is an alternative sigma factor** regulated by the global iron regulator Fur

So putting all the pieces together, can I say that my genes could be upregulated or downregulated by this PvdS sigma factor, that is a sigma factor that means a protein needed for initiation of transcription in bacteria and this protein, in this particular case, is encoded by the regulatory gene PvdS that regulates the expression of the pvd gene involved in the pyoverdin biosynthesis?  And thus the PvdS sigma factor is a protein for initiation of transcription of the pvd genes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a site for specific problems about biology that can be regarded as of general interest. It is not a site for discussing the research data of particular individuals. As for the function of the actual pad gene, you have found out more than anyone here is likely to know. I assume that you know what sigma factors are, or can read about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clarification of the Question**

It appears to me that the question posed in the title of this question, “What is sigma factor PvdS?” is answered by the poster — it is a sigma factor that is specific for, and allows transcription of, genes involved in pyoverdin synthesis in *Pseudomonas aeruginosa*. I assume that the poster knows that a sigma factor is a subunit of bacterial RNA polymerase that must associate with it before it is capable of initiating transcription. (The information is readily available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_factor) or in [Berg *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22546/#A3961))

The bulk of the actual question is devoted to describing the results of computer analysis of the genome of an unspecified archaeon. Towards the end the poster poses a question:

> …can I say that my genes *could be* upregulated or downregulated by this PvdS sigma factor…

[The sentence continues for several lines. The emphasis is mine.]

I therefore interpret the question as asking

> What conclusions can be drawn from computer analysis of the type
> performed, with particular reference to the biological system
> described?

**Answer**

It is necessary to emphasize at the outset that the conclusions that can be derived from studies performed *in silico* are severely constrained.

Sequence similarity allows you to **suggest** that an experimentally uncharacterised gene **might** encode a protein with a similar function to a related gene. No more. Only experimental analysis of the protein allows you to state what its function **actually** is.

The usual type of annotation of such proteins (and by extension their genes) is one of:

- [hypothetical xxxxxx protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_protein)
- putative xxxxxx protein
- possible xxxxxx protein
- xxxxxx-like protein
- xxxxxx-domain protein

Likewise, the occurrence of a motif that allows pyoverdin genes to be recognized by a transcription factor in *P. aeruginosa* can only **suggest** that a functionally uncharacterized gene from a different organism **might** be similarly recognized and its transcription regulated in a similar manner.

In the example in question the most it is possible to say is that a system of gene regulation similar to that in *P. aeruginosa* **may** exist in the archaeon. To go any further one would need to identify (the gene for) for the putative sigma factor, show that it allowed the RNA polymerase to bind to the genes, and either show this affected transcription directly or perform genetic experiments that would allow the same conclusion.

Furthermore, I would be wary of describing the putative sigma factor as ‘PvdS’ unless the proteins predicted to be encoded by genes on which this motif is found bear a similarity to the genes for synthesis of pyoverdin, from which its gene name, pvdS, is derived. (A [BLAST](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi) search should, of course, be done on the genes to determine this — probably *blastx*.)

Comment: I think the OP is not a native English speaker and so some of the question phrasing is cumbersome as a result. I interpreted "could" as similar in meaning to your "suggest".

Comment: Since the objection about the fact that I was discussing my research data and the different votes to close the question for the same reason (I think), I removed the last part (I already imagined that it could be source of troubles). So just knowing what sigma factor PvdS means would be great ! @David

Comment: Anyway, I was asking if my genes could be regulated by the same factor indicated by the software (sigma factor PvdS) . I did not ask if they might encode a certain protein...

Comment: @Manuela The principle for genes is the same, but I have now spelled it out. It is of little use asking what "could" be on a site which is concerned with objective answers to precise questions in biology. Many things are possible, but how probable is an objective judgement. The key point of my answer is that you can only go far *in silico* — to draw any real conclusions (certainly publishable ones) you need to do experiments or convince an experimental scientist that they are worth doing.

Comment: @Armand I am aware that the poster is not a native speaker as I have helped her previously. My impression is that she wants to go further than "suggest" — modal verbs in English and romance or germanic languages do tend to differ in usage, but they are one of the things that are emphasized and one learns early on in a language. Even if this were so she is asking a question that is impossible to answer without seeing all of her data, and is even then off-topic as it does not constitute a general biological problem.

Comment: Thank you @David for the answer ! As regards the first part of my question, I still have a doubt: is PvdS the gene that encodes the sigma factor that allows transcription of genes involved in pyoverdin synthesis in *Pseudomonas aeruginosa* ?

Comment: For the second part (interpretation of the motif), thank you! I wanted only to know if this motif could have any relevant meaning (=if this suggests a meaning for the motif, as @Armand said). I think that when you do de novo motif discovery using MEME or other softwares, the results are always suggestions.

Comment: So, finally, the very last suggestion: did you mean that I should compare the proteins encoded by my genes and the proteins encoded by the genes for synthesis of pyoverdin to say if they are recognized for transcription by the same factor (PvdS) ? Is this a little replacement of the experiment? Or did I completely misunderstand your last suggestion?

Comment: @Manuela —My guess is that you are at some advanced level of education with a training in the numeric sciences but no real knowledge of molecular biology trying to use bioinformatics tools on a problem. It would helpt to know if it is one of your own devising, one given you in a Bioinformatics course or in a lab where you are doing a project is relevant in terms of advice. To answer your question, you should do a BLAST search on each of the genes (or probably better protein translations) that have the motif associated with PvdS to see what they are related to. Surely you know BLAST?

Comment: @David no there is no bioinformatics course or lab. It is just for an exam project and I took data from ncbi after reading a paper. I have a physics background and I wanted to go towards biophysics, so yes no real knowledge of molecular biology, unfortunately, thus interpreting some results is difficult for me ... Anyway, yes I know BLAST, so thank you for the suggestion ! The fact was simply that I was surprised to find this common motif in two genes which encode proteins with similar biological function but of two different organisms which belong to two different domains.

Comment: As your archaea genome must have been published and, I imagine, the genes annotated, BLAST may not be necessary, at least in the first instance. Just assemble the annotations and see if they indicate genes that encode proteins similar to those in the pyoverdin synthetic pathway or perhaps some other pathway. If there is no useful annotation, then you would need BLAST.  If the putative proteins do not hang together (obviously there may be exceptions), your argument probably doesn't either.